# Warning when build maven

Tags: java, maven-2, warnings

A Warning showed "[WARNING] Failed to initialize environment variable resolver. Skipping environment substitution in settings." when i use mvn install -P [evn]. What is the meaning of warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Check your environment for blank
>   entries, entries without = and also
>   check your path for a . (dot) - if a .
>   Exists in your path - remove it.
>
> Check this out
>   http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1819

-source : http://www.mail-archive.com